# Continuous mapping from a Topological space to a Kolmogorov space

Tags: general-topology

Let X be a topological space and let K be a Kolmogorov space or T<sub>0</sub> space. Let's say I have a continuous mapping from X to K, say *f*, which gives *f*(m)=x and *f*(n)=y, where x,y ∈ K and m,n ∈ X. Since K is a T<sub>0</sub> space we may assume without loss of generality that, ∃ an open set containing x and not containing y. Let us call this G.

My doubt is, if x ∈ G and y ∉ G, then, is it guaranteed that m ∈ *f* <sup>-1</sup>(G) and n ∉ *f* <sup>-1</sup>(G)?

Why?/Why not?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  Take any constant function.  Then both $m$ and $n$ will be in $f^{-1}(G)$